# Optimizing Elasticsearch for Parallel Queries

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark, lucene, full-text-search

I've got an index of about 3gb on a 20 node Elasticsearch cluster running in AWS EMR. The index has 5 shards and is replicated 4 times. The underlying data are books, but I've split them into paragraph or line chunks, depending on formatting, so there are about 27million documents. Indexing only takes ~5 mins.

I have about 15 million phrases I want to search for in the index.

The search logic is a 4 layered waterfall that stops once results are found: exact match => fuzzy match with an edit distance of 1 => fuzzy match with an edit distance of 2 => partial phrase match. I broke it down this way, so I could filter the matches by some quality measure.

In order to distribute and execute the searches, I'm using Spark.

I'm finding that the quickest I can get the search to run is about 420 phrases a second, which means the entire task will take 10-12 hours.

**My question is:** is that a reasonable search rate?

Would I get better performance if I had the entire index on one shard and replicated the full index on each node? Or should I go the other direction and increase the sharding level? I suspect the answers to these two questions will be **"Try both!"**, which I'll likely do in the long run, but I have a short term deadline that I'm trying to optimize for, so I wanted to see if anyone else had experience with a similar problem.

I'm happy to provide more details as need.

Apologies if this isn't on topic - I'm not finding a lot of documentation on this sort of use case for Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 2):

Having **only** 3gb of data on 20 nodes is a waste of resources. If you have a 5-shard index, start with 5 nodes only. Heck, 3gb is so small that you could even have that index only contain a single shard and run on a single node.

You're lucky that it only takes 5 minutes to index all your data, as you'll quickly find the right cluster size to run your queries optimally. Start with one primary shard (no replica) on one node, then add one replica and another node, etc

Then start over with two primary shards and two nodes, add replicas and nodes, etc.

For each test, measure how fast it goes, and at some point (i.e. within a day or two) you'll find the exact cluster size that is optimal for your search requirements.

**UPDATE**

If you have 32 CPUs per node, you can have a single node and your twenty shards on it. During each search, each CPU will happily tackle one shard, there will be less network chatter to aggregate the results and it "should" be faster. I would definitely try it out.

Comment: Agreed - the 20 nodes are necessary to increase the parallel capacity of the search - without those, all things equal, that 340 searches a second would drop to about 85 searches a second.

Comment: So you basically have 20 shards and 20 nodes, so one shard per node, right? how many CPUs do you have on each node?

Comment: At the moment, I have 5 shards and 4 replicas distributed across the 20 nodes. The nodes are AWS r3.8xlarge, so 32 CPU's each. I'm toying with trying one shard per node instead, since the index is so small that the gain from distributing might be negligible.

Comment: If you have 32 CPUs per node, you can have a single node and your twenty shards on it. During each search, each CPU will happily tackle one shard, there will be less network chatter to aggregate the results and it "should" be faster. I would definitely try it out.

Comment: Definitely worth a shot - I guess I was concerned the I/O on one node, but in that case I could also create a separate Elasticsearch instance on each node and have each Spark worker only query it's local instance. My first iteration of this project did just that, but used the python package Whoosh for indexing/searching.

Comment: Also, I should mention the 5min indexing was possible because I distributed  that process over Spark as well. I haven't tried it on a single node yet.

Comment: There are many more knobs to tune, but there's no magic, you need to start small, tune one knob after another, measure, rinse and repeat. OK, let us know how it goes.

Comment: +1 for the answer and your second comment. I also believe that the upvoted comment should be in your answer.

Comment: Thanks @eliasah, makes sense, I've updated my answer accordingly